# Using Select Case in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Just curious but is there any way to reduce this to smaller number of lines of code?

```
For k = 1 To 12
    Select Case k
        Case 1
            col = 9
        Case 2
            col = 10
        Case 3
            col = 11
        Case 4
            col = 12
        Case 5
            col = 13
        Case 6
            col = 14
        Case 7
            col = 15
        Case 8
            col = 16
        Case 9
            col = 17
        Case 10
            col = 18
        Case 11
            col = 19
        Case 12
            col = 20
    End Select
Next
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
For k = 1 to 12
   col = k + 8
Next
```

Or what you were probably looking for:

```
For k = 1 To 12
    Select Case k
        Case 1 To 12
            col = k + 8
    End Select
Next
```

Here's the [relevant MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you can scroll down for examples.

Comment: Sweeeet!! I knew they had to be a more better way of looping. thanks a lot

Comment: might want to add an else clause for safety

Comment: @PreetSangha Perhaps, but for this example it's really not needed. I considered it, but the OP wanted less lines and adding that would add no value in this circumstance.